# iOS - How to present different scenes from UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, tableview, uitableview

I have a `UIViewController` with a `TableView`. The `TableView` is populated with an image and a text for each cell. Now I need to present others `Scenes` when the user taps a cell. For example:

- tap on first row --> present `ViewController1` 
 - tap on second row --> present `ViewController2`

`ViewController1` and `ViewController2` are scenes in my `Storyboard`.

I've tried various solutions, but none of these works. Moreover it seems that the method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` is not called when I tap a cell (for example I tried to show up an alert).

Here the code of my ViewController: 
**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
{
    NSArray *recipes;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    recipes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"News", @"Calendar",@"Take a photo",@"Draw",@"Mail us",@"Follow us on Facebook", nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [recipes count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [recipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if ([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:recipes[0]]) {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"newsicon"];
    }
    else if ([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:recipes[1]]) {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mensaicon"];
    }
    else if ([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:recipes[2]]) {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fotoicon"];
    }
    else if ([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:recipes[3]]) {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"drawicon"];
    }
    else if ([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:recipes[4]]) {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mailicon"];
    }
    else if ([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:recipes[5]]) {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fbicon"];
    }

    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // here we get the cell from the selected row.
    UITableViewCell *selectedCell=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([selectedCell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:recipes[0]]) {
        UIAlertView *messageAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                     initWithTitle:@"Row Selected" message:@"You've selected a row" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

        // Display Alert Message
        [messageAlert show];

        NSString *storyboardName = @"Main";
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
        UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"news"];
        [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
    }

    // use the image in the next window using view controller instance of that view.
}


@end
```

I'm new to iOS developing, so I don't know if my code is right or if there are other solutions more elegant of these. Anyway, let's focus on the problem, can anyone help me?

Comment: Your `didSelectedRowAtIndexPath` does not called because of image that you have added over cell. Please set property of imageView cell.imageView.userInteractionEnabled= false. After this your `didSelectedRowAtIndexPath` called. Also set Delegate and DataSource like `self.tabelView.delegate = self; self.tableView.datasource = self;` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your view is only a table view I'd suggest using a UITableViewController instead of a UIViewController.  If you have a UITableView in an existing UIViewController you need to set up the delegate and data source methods yourself.
You can do this in the storyboard.  Click on your tableView and then select the connections inspector.  Then click the circle next to dataSource and drag it to your view controller.  Do the same for delegate.  This is probably why your table view methods aren't being called.

If it's a static table, you can create independent segues from each cell in the storyboard.

Comment: ...facepalm. I know that, but I have forgot to drag the delegate to the view controller. What a stupid error. Thank you for having reminded me it. Probably everyone here tried to say it, but your reply has been the one that made me understand what's happened.

Answer (score 1):

> Moreover it seems that the method didSelectRowAtIndexPath: is not called when I tap a cell (for example I tried to show up an alert).

Your based class is `UIViewController`, therefore, your `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` won't get set automatically. You need to do it yourself. For example, you can set them in the `init` function:

```
- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if( self ) {
        self.delegate = self;
        self.datasource = self;
    } 
    return self; 
}
```

An alternative is to use `UITableViewController` as your base call, then you don't need to worry about setting the delegates.

Comment: @Kurtis92, in .m file and you can put them before viewDidLoad function

Answer (score 0):

according to your code alert will only be shown when you click on 1st cell only..
but according to your needs let me write a code for that will help you..

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // here we get the cell from the selected row.
    NSString *selectedcelltext=[recipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UIAlertView *messageAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                 initWithTitle:@"Row Selected" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"You've selected a %@ row ",selectedcelltext] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    // Display Alert Message
    [messageAlert show];


    if ([selectedcelltext isEqualToString:recipes[0]]) {

        NSString *storyboardName = @"Main";
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
        UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"news"];
        [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else  if ([selectedcelltext isEqualToString:recipes[1]]) {

        NSString *storyboardName = @"Main";
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
        UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"calendar"];
        [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
    }


    // use the image in the next window using view controller instance of that view.
}
```